# How to get a password from gnome-keyring

Tags: passwords, jabber, password-recovery, gnome-keyring

I have recently forgotten password for my jabber account, which doesn't have any simple way to reset it (e-mail only). I have this password stored however on gajim on one of computers I use (I have root access). Gajim stores the password with gnome-keyring. What is the simplest way to obtain this password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a very interesting [blog post from Michael Schurter](http://blog.schmichael.com/2008/10/30/listing-all-passwords-stored-in-gnome-keyring/) with a Python script which extracts all passwords from the keyring, which is basically the same functionality which is achieved via [Seahorse](http://live.gnome.org/Seahorse).

The comments are also pointing to a little [Pyhton application called gkeyring](https://launchpad.net/gkeyring), which does the same thing.